# How can I add a progress bar on Zip extracting in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar, google-colaboratory, python-zip

I have a large dataset in Google Drive. I'm using Google Colab. I extracted the dataset in a cell of colab using python.
But I have to wait till it finished. 
**Is there any way to add a progress bar to this Code in down below?**
So that it shows the progress of extracting.

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/Dataset/dataset.zip','r') as zip_file:
  zip_file.extractall('df')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract ZipFile using Python, display Progress Percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341584/extract-zipfile-using-python-display-progress-percentage)

Comment: Not working with tqdm.

Comment: Link given by @jordanm works well for me!