# How can I insert a progress bar in this code with python zipfile?

Tags: python, multithreading, progress-bar, python-asyncio, python-zipfile

im trying to give a progress bar to this code with zipfile module:

```
object = zipfile.ZipFile(name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_LZMA)
object.write(f'{self.dir}\\{new_archive}')
os.remove(f"{self.dir}\\{new_archive}")
```

How can I do this?
ps: this function runs in other threads

I tried with TQDM but without success.

edit: How can I measure zipfile module wait time while zipping?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Similar to [Extract ZipFile using Python, display Progress Percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341584/extract-zipfile-using-python-display-progress-percentage)

Comment: no, I need to zip and not extract, the extraction already has a "predefined" size